# Small cracks on motorcycle rear tire

Tags: motorcycle, tires, cracking

My motorcycle rear tire has developed small cracks (not very deep) on its entire circumference, along the middle of the tread.

[image: Rear tire]

Is this something I should be concerned about? Should I bring it to the dealership, since it is under warranty? The motorcycle is new, last year's model, and I've put around 1,500 miles on it before noticing the cracks. The tires are Dunlop Sportmax.

Comment: Just adding an update here. The tire now has around 9500 miles, the cracks never went away (and got worse some time ago), but that never affected handling of the motorcycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about here; this is normal wear and tear associated with tire usage.

As such, it is unlikely to be covered by any warranty.

Answer (score 1):

How's your driving? Have you been accelerating rapidly during takeoff lately? It could be a normal sign of wear of the rear tire which transmits the power to the ground.
I'd say it's OK, but if the bike is new and you're not sure, go back to the dealer and ask them. 
ALWAYS wear a helmet.

Comment: Not really, pretty normal usage. I'll bring that up on the next regular-interval service, though. Thanks.